# How do I change the contents of an unordered list using Data attributes and JS objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, custom-data-attribute

I have dynamic list items that need to change based on the input of a range slider. I am using an  in my HTML and the

have data attributes. I created JS objects that I would like to use to populate the list depending on where the slider is.

Here is my HTML:

```
<p>Equivelant impact to:</p>
      <ul id="impact-list">
        <li data-miles></li>
        <li data-coal></li>
        <li data-waste></li>
      </ul>
```

here are my objects:

```
const sbImpactTen = {
  miles: "3,418 less miles driven",
  coal: "1,524 less pounds of coal burned",
  waste: "60 trash bags of waste recycled"
}

const sbImpactFifty = {
  miles: "17,000 less miles driven",
  coal: "8,000 less pounds of coal burned",
  waste: "300 trash bags of waste recycled"
}

const sbImpactHundred = {
  miles: "34,000 less miles driven",
  coal: "15,000 less pounds of coal burned",
  waste: "3,596 trash bags of waste recycled"
}
```

and here is the function:

```
var sbSlider = document.getElementById("location-range-slider");
var output = document.getElementById("value");

var cost = document.getElementById("monthly-cost");

var impact = document.getElementById("impact-list");

output.innerHTML = "10";

sbSlider.oninput = function() {
  if (sbSlider.value === "1") {
    output.innerHTML = "10",
    cost.innerHTML = "$5",
    impact.innerHTML = sbImpactTen;
  } else if (sbSlider.value === "2") {
    output.innerHTML = "50",
    cost.innerHTML = "$20",
    impact.innerHTML = sbImpactFifty;
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = "100",
    cost.innerHTML = "$40",
    impact.innerHTML = sbImpactHundred;
  }
}
```

I am also including my [codepen](https://codepen.io/RECopeland/pen/rNvzMjg) for viewing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about those other values, but for the HTML you show, just use `querySelector` and the data-attributes to target the elements

```js
let impact = document.querySelector("#impact-list")
let slider = document.querySelector('.sbSlider');
const sbImpactTen = {
  miles: "3,418 less miles driven",
  coal: "1,524 less pounds of coal burned",
  waste: "60 trash bags of waste recycled"
}

const sbImpactFifty = {
  miles: "17,000 less miles driven",
  coal: "8,000 less pounds of coal burned",
  waste: "300 trash bags of waste recycled"
}
const sbImpactHundred = {
  miles: "34,000 less miles driven",
  coal: "15,000 less pounds of coal burned",
  waste: "3,596 trash bags of waste recycled"
}
// listen to the changes 
slider.addEventListener('input', e => adjustData(e.target))

const adjustData = el => {
  let useImpact
  if (el.value === "1") {
    useImpact = sbImpactTen;
  } else if (el.value === "2") {
    useImpact = sbImpactFifty;
  } else {
    useImpact = sbImpactHundred;
  }
  for (let i in useImpact) {
    impact.querySelector(`li[data-${i}]`).innerHTML = useImpact[i]
  }
}


// kick it off with the default value
adjustData(slider)
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="sbSlider" id="myRange">
<hr>
<p>Equivelant impact to:</p>
<ul id="impact-list">
  <li data-miles></li>
  <li data-coal></li>
  <li data-waste></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful, thank you @Kinglish. Why would I get the following error though? 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')**

Comment: SOLVED: found the error in my code and fixed it. I was missing the class name sbSlider that you added to the HTML.  Thank you @Kinglish!